# JS: calculate range numbers like [-10, 10] using percentage and get number according to the percent value

Tags: javascript

I have a range of numbers like **[-10, 10]**.
I want to get the number according to a percent.
For example, with **50%** I should get **0**. And for **100%** I should get **10**.

I'm thinking of a function to get `percent`, `min` and `max` numbers and return the calculated number.
Like:

```
function getRangeNumber(percent, min, max){
  // do some math here... 
}
```

How should I calculate it with JavaScript? Anyone can help?

Comment: How would you do it with pencil and paper?

Comment: You know how you get a random number in a range? It's the same only it's not random, you have the `percent` to use instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally you want `min` + the percentage of the difference between `max` and `min`, *e.g.*:

```js
function getRangeNumber(percent, min, max) {
  return min + (max - min) * percent / 100;
}
console.log(getRangeNumber(50, -10, 10));    
console.log(getRangeNumber(0, -10, 10));
console.log(getRangeNumber(100, -10, 10));
```

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do is add the percentage of the range to your min.

In your first example, this is -10 + 50% * 20 = 0.

In your second example, this is -10 + 100% * 20 = 10.

And in javascript, that looks like this: `min + (percent / 100) * (max - min)`

Note that the range is given by `(max - min)`.

Here is a working code snippet for the two examples you gave:

```js
console.log(getRangeNumber(50, -10, 10));
console.log(getRangeNumber(100, -10, 10));

function getRangeNumber(percent, min, max){
   return min + (percent / 100) * (max - min);
}
```